# Play .m4a by remote url in iOS with react-native-track-player

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-track-player

I'm trying to use [react-native-track-player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player) library in my project for both ios and android and I faced a problem.

All my files(remote URLs) are `.m4a` and they're playing just fine on android but the library raises an error on ios: `{“error”: “Cannot Open”, “type”: “playback-error”}`

When I replace .m4a file with .mp3 it works on ios but I would like to use .m4a.

Does anyone know why it does not work on iOS but works on android with .m4a? And how to force it to work on ios without converting m4a to mp3?

P.S. This library suits my needs very well so I want to keep it

Comment: can you give me a URL of .m4a file?

Comment: Sure, for example this: https://files.stivisto.com/file/stivisto-drive-dev/1c7b7cf3cde1e68fde0435656185d0ac05971a9b-917e-4865-b66c-e8851d78ef51.m4a

Although I think the file should be fine since it works on android

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the exact same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: @MyPro Nope, I gave up on my project ;(